# Why "sam <-sample(1:1000,50) y<-x[sam]" it´s not the same as "y<-x[sample(1:1000,50)]"?

Tags: r

It caused me a lot of problems, I wasted so much time trying to identify where was my error comparing between two codes and seems the error was this little difference:

My code

```
Xm <-x[sample(1:1000,50)]
Ym <-y[sample(1:1000,50)]
```

The code I was comparing to (and gives to the correct result):

```
extract<-sample(1:1000,50)

Xm <-x[extract]
Ym <-y[extract]
```

In my head it´s the same thing I cannot figure out what´s the difference. I hope someone can help me. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Because sampling involves random numbers. Each call of sample returns a different set of numbers. In your first code your sample twice. So you extract different elements from x and y. In your second you sample once. Therefore you extract the same elements. See the answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because in the first example you are calling `sample` twice which changes the index to subset.

Consider this example :

```
x <- 1:10
y <- 11:20
x[sample(1:10, 2)]
#[1] 10  9 #10th and 9th value got subsetted
y[sample(1:10, 2)]
#[1] 13 14 #3rd and 4th value got subsetted
```

whereas in second example you call `sample` only once and use it to subset.

```
inds <- sample(1:10, 2)
x[inds]
#[1] 10  7 #10th and 7th value got subsetted
y[inds]
#[1] 20 17 #Same 10th and 7th value got subsetted
```

Comment: Sure, I couldn't  never imagined it, thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

Your first code will work if the vector you wish to sample from and the sample size is less than or equal to the number of elements in `x` and `y`.

```
x <- rnorm(1500) 
y <- rnorm(1500)

# will work
smplVEC <- 1:1000  # sample from this vector
n.smpl <- 50       # sample size

length(smplVEC) <= length(x)
[1] TRUE
length(smplVEC) <= length(y)
[1] TRUE    
n.smpl <= length(x)
[1] TRUE
n.smpl <= length(y)
[1] TRUE

# no error returned
x[sample(smplVEC, n.smpl)] # x[sample(1:1000, 50)]
y[sample(smplVEC, n.smpl)] # y[sample(1:1000, 50)]


# will not work
smplVEC <- 1:2000  # sample from this vector
n.smpl <- 2500     # sample size

length(smplVEC) <= length(x)
[1] FALSE
length(smplVEC) <= length(y)
[1] FALSE    
n.smpl <= length(x)
[1] FALSE
n.smpl <= length(y)
[1] FALSE

# error returned
x[sample(smplVEC, n.smpl)] # x[sample(1:2000, 2500)]
y[sample(smplVEC, n.smpl)] # y[sample(1:2000, 2500)]
```

Answer (score 0):

If we want to get the same output, specify a `seed` and it should give the same index

```
x <- 1:10
y <- 11:20
set.seed(24)
x[sample(1:10, 2)]
#[1] 7 3   #7th and 3rd element
set.seed(24)
y[sample(1:10, 2)]
#[1] 17 13 #7th and 3rd element
```

However, it would be better to create an object as in the OP's second code block ('extract')